# Filename with a hash is displayed instead of image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image, erb

In header.erb:

```
"<% = asset_path ('logo.png')%>"
```

This picture was found and displayed, but not in the form of a picture, but in the form of symbols:

```
/assets/logo-d98a3c54ea97a8cc159de8a6dbf448acd2cb8717c051ad8d02a577546ee013ab.png
```

Has anyone encountered a similar problem?

Comment: This is the correct and expected behaviour for `asset_path` - it returns the path and filename for an asset, including supporting [fingerprinting](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark). To generate an HTML `img` tag and display the image, replace `asset_path` with `image_tag` i.e `<%= image_tag('logo.png') %>`

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is right, the [`asset_path ('logo.png')`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark) getting the file resources path, if you need to show the image using `asset_path` then it will be like this

```
<img src="<%= asset_path ('logo.png')%>">
```

the `logo-331238805bdaebb4b05e9385bc1261f8.png` it's called [FINGERPRINT](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark).

if you want to disable the [FINGERPRINTING](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#what-is-fingerprinting-and-why-should-i-care-questionmark) in the development mode then go to `config/environment/development.rb` and swt the [`config.assets.digest = false`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#turning-digests-off)

it will show the image, but this is not the rails way to show image the rails way is [`image_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag) like

```
<%= image_tag('logo.png')%>
```

make sure the image under the `assets/images/`